# Can I convert an lxml div object to a string?

Tags: python, lxml

I'm making a program to scrape text from a website.

But the website puts its text in a `div` tag and sometimes the text is inside a `p` tag inside the `div` tag.

Is it possible to convert this `div` tag into a string so that it would be simpler to format?

```
from lxml import etree
import requests
element = etree.HTML(requests.get('a website')).xpath('//div')
```

Comment: Little bit more information will make it a good question I am sure.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us sample data and the output you want to generate from it.

Answer (score 0):

just like this

```
from lxml import etree
import requests

el = etree.HTML(requests.get('a website').content).xpath('//div')

# then for first div (if it exist's)

print(etree.tostring(el[0]))
```